# Human datetime diffs with Pendulum

Tags: python, datetime, pendulum

I've recently stumbled upon this awesome [`pendulum`](https://pendulum.eustace.io/) "datetimes made easy" library.

It has a very nice feature of displaying "human like" diffs between datetimes:

```
In [1]: import pendulum

In [2]: now = pendulum.now()

In [3]: future = now.add(years=10)

In [4]: future.diff_for_humans()
Out[4]: '10 years from now'
```

But, is it possible to make it work for a more complicated difference - say "years" and "weeks"?

```
In [5]: future = now.add(years=10, weeks=5)

In [6]: future.diff_for_humans()
Out[6]: '10 years from now'
```

I would expect it to output `10 years and 5 weeks from now`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Pendulum module readme:

```
now = pendulum.now()
future = now.add(years=10, weeks=5)
delta = future - now
delta.in_words()
>>>'10 years 1 month 4 days'
```

https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum

Comment: Good finding, I wonder why there is this difference between the `diff_for_humans()` and `in_words()`. Thanks!

Comment: You could always look in the implementation for that. I linked the module sources.

Comment: Okay, [read the source, Luke](https://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/) :)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question if the `'from now'` is desired. Just adding that manually isn't an option when localization is required.

Comment: You could call pendulum.now(timezone) as your "now" value. Also in_words has a locale param. Worst comes to worst, just do string transformations if your locale is not supported. Or submit a merge request to the module maintainers with your locale :D

Comment: I just opened an issue for this: https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum/issues/169.